# detrend time series data for non-regression proposal

Tags: regression, time-series, trend, copula, vine-copula

Suppose I have a time-series data (temperature and ice-cream sales). I would like to fit a copula model to this data (just to understand the dependency between these two variables. I do not want to fit a regression copula model). My question is, do I need to detrend the data? As I understand I can detrend the data only if I need to fit a regression model.

Comment: You don't need to de-trend if you just want to fit a regression model, at least not in general. Are you fitting a linear model?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I try to fit a copula model